# Unable to access values from Pointer receiver

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface, scheduler

I'm unable to get value from Pointer receiver. It keeps returning memory address.
I'm trying to access values from the pointer receivers from other file in this below format

```
package types

import (
    // "Some product related imports"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "time"
)

type TestContext struct {
    userId string
}

func (cont *TestContext) GetUserId() string {
    return cont.userId
}
```

I'm trying to solve it through multiple ways but either getting memory address, `nil` values or error.

Comment: This is just a syntax error. If `myType` is not a pointer you cannot dereference it by prefixing it with `*`. If you want to get the address you need the address of operator `&`. Take the Tour of Go once more for this type of basics.

Comment: @Volker can you mind guiding me about the technique 1? I'm not using pointer reference in that but still getting memory address instead of value.

Comment: You are not writing Go code. If you want to invoke a function you must invoke a function with `()`. You really _must_ take the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 1):

Always write clean code:

1. Name `userID` not `userId`.
2. Name `UserID()` not `GetUserId()`.
3. use `ctx2 := &myType.myType{}` instead of `ctx2 := *myType.myType{}`.
4. try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/d2V6ImN43gz) code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myType struct {
    userID string
}

func (cont *myType) UserID() string {
    return cont.userID
}

func main() {
    ctx1 := myType{"1"}
    fmt.Println(ctx1.UserID()) // 1

    ctx := myType{"2"}
    var101 := ctx.UserID()
    fmt.Println(ctx1.UserID(), var101) // 1 2

    ctx2 := &myType{}
    fmt.Println(ctx2) // &{}

    var ctx3 *myType
    fmt.Println(ctx3) // <nil>
}
```

Output:

```
1
1 2
&{}
<nil>
```

Answer (score -1):

For Technique 1. I'm not sure what logging.Debug() does but I think you are trying to pass a string to it. In this case use `ctx2.GetUserId()` not `ctx2.GetUserId`. I know it's sounds silly but to call a function that takes no parameters you still need the brackets.

The major problem is that you are using the myType package but you think you are using the types package. Otherwise I think technique 2 would be OK.

And as Volker implied about tehcnique 3 you need to use `&` not `*` to take the address of an object.